# Input radio button function not working on jQuery 1.10.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

Why is this code not working on jQuery 1.10.1? 
Fiddle here -> http://jsfiddle.net/XgDwU/9/

```
<input type="radio" id="don" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" value="">Ship to this address</input>
<input type="radio" id="don1" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" value="">Ship to different address</input>
<br/><br/>
<b> <input type="checkbox" id="chkSelect" /> Check/Uncheck me </b>
<br/><br/>
<p></p>
```

here's my function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#chkSelect').click(function(){

    var isChecked = $('#chkSelect').is(':checked');
      if(isChecked){
          $("input#don").attr('checked',true);
          $('p').html('Checkbox is checked: <b>True</b>');
      }else{
          $("input#don1").attr('checked',true);
          $('p').html('Checkbox is checked: <b>False</b>');
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: what is not working??

Comment: after the first loop it stop. but if you change jQuery version to 1.6 or higher it is working fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems:

1. Use `change` event instead of `click`
2. Use `prop` instead of `attr`
3. I have use `this.checked` in place of `$('#chkSelect').is(':checked')`

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#chkSelect').change(function(){
      if(this.checked){
          $("input#don").prop('checked',true);
          $('p').html('Checkbox is checked: <b>True</b>');
      }else{
          $("input#don1").prop('checked',true);
          $('p').html('Checkbox is checked: <b>False</b>');
      }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XgDwU/11/)

You should read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) a very good explanation is provided

Comment: Thanks man! Excellent! :) anyway, how is it differ? prop and attr?

Comment: @user3364265, You should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr a very good explanation is provided

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a check attribute to a radio button. If more than one radio button in a set has the `checked` attribute, the latter will be checked. That's what's happening, more than one radio is being checked.

Since it's a radio button, and the browser handles the switching, just trigger a click on the one that you want:

```
$('#chkSelect').click(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("input#don").click();
        $('p').html('Checkbox is checked: <b>True</b>');
    } else {
        $("input#don1").click();
        $('p').html('Checkbox is checked: <b>False</b>');
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XgDwU/12/)